# After export in eclipse things change

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

When creating GUI application in java through eclipse and I run the program everything functions correctly and looks sharp with the right colors. After I export the program to a runnable on my desktop then run it from there images are missing and the colors change. For ex. Color.GRAY becomes a really light gray. Some things also become pixely.

Why does it do this does anyone know or do I first need to post more detailed information and code? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Missing images:

1. Best use resources on the class path (i.e. inside the jar), not File (the file system). `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/a/b/c.png")`.
2. Files on Windows are case insensitive. Everywhere else case-sensitive, especially in a jar. Open the jar with 7zip or so and compare the paths with those in the code.

   ```
   ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/a/b/c.png"));
   ```

Colors:

- Do not use `.gif` risking several effects, but `.png` (exact images) or `.jpg` (photos).

Remainder

- Sharp images are drawn with the correct resolution: width an height. Also one may call `Graphics2D.setRenderingHints`.

Comment: Then how would I take this getClass().getRecourseAsStream(String) object and convert it to an ImageIcon?

Comment: Added to answer, URL getResource will do. If resource not found, a null URL is returned, so take care.

Comment: When I use getRecourses() it throws a NullPointerException but it doesn't do that when I just do new ImageIcon("path") The file clearly exists but getRecourses() throws null. Any idea why?

Comment: The .png should be in the application jar. Open the jar with 7zip or WinZip and check the path. Must be case-sensitive.

Comment: I have opened up the .jar before with unarchiver since I use a mac and yes it is right where I have placed it when setting up the project: src/Recourses/Images/OnButton.png

Answer (score 0):

getClass().getResource(String path) solved the problem although it does not make sense to me why things should change like this when exporting to runnable. Another thing I had to do was unlike new ImageIcon(src/Resources/Images/OnButton.png) I had to use a different file path with getResource("/Resources/Images/OnButton.png) again not sure why but it worked.

@JoopEggen your method for getting rid of the pixely look after export worked thanks so much!

Thanks for all the help guys!